# Using FindRoot[] to find an inflection point

Tags: equation-solving

```
FindRoot[
  {Derivative[2][SinIntegral[x]], 0 < x < (Pi)},
  x
]
```

[image: plot of the function of interest]

I hoped that my code would return a value for x=0 but it is returning an error:
"search specification should be a list with 1 to 5 elements"

edit: I want to iterate this multiple times so it will be helpful to be able to find the root within a given range for x

Comment: To see the shape: `Plot[SinIntegral''[x], {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}]` and then choose a suitable initial guess: `FindRoot[SinIntegral''[x], {x, 5}]`

Comment: For the interval `0 <= x <= 6 Pi` use `sol = FindRoot[SinIntegral''[x], {x, #}] & /@ {1/20, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17}`

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

```
FindRoot[Derivative[2][SinIntegral][x], {x, 1/2}]
```

> `{x -> 1.15898*10^-10}`

```
sol=NSolve[{Derivative[2][SinIntegral][x], 0 < x < 6 Pi}, x]
```

> `{{x -> 4.49341}, {x -> 7.72525}, {x -> 10.9041}, {x -> 14.0662}, {x -> 17.2208}}`

The concave and convex parts as below.

```
Plot[SinIntegral[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Mesh -> {sol}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 MeshShading -> {Cyan, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Limit[SinIntegral''[x], x -> 0]` also evaluates to `0`

Comment: The important thing for the OP to keep in mind here is that `FindRoot` (used in their original code) is designed to find one root and one root only, while `NSolve` can (sometimes) find all of the roots in a given range.